# Error : xxx does not name a type

Tags: c++

I get the error "xxx does not name a type" in the first line of the code when trying to compile it.
Know that "poligono" is a base class of "triangulo" and that i wrote the .cpp and the .h
files.

I would like to know the way I can fix this error

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "poligono.h"
using namespace std;
triangulo :: triangulo(int x1i, int x2i, int x3i, int y1i, int y2i, int y3i, string clasei, int ancho, int alto, int puntos) :: poligono(int ancho, int alto, int puntos){

    this-> x1 = x1i;

    this-> x2 = x2i;

    this-> x3 = x3i;

    this-> y1 = y1i;

    this-> y2 = y2i;

    this-> y3 = y3i;

}


triangulo :: triangulo(int x1, int x2, int x3, int y1, int y2, int y3, string clasei, const otro&) :: poligono (otro.ancho, otro.alto, otro.puntos){

    this-> x1 = otro.x1;
    this-> x2 = otro.x2;
    this-> x3 = otro.x3;
    this-> y1 = otro.y1;
    this-> y2 = otro.y2;
    this-> y3 = otro.y3;

    this->clase = clasei;




}
```

---

```
#ifndef TRIANGULO_H
#define TRIANGULO_H
#include "poligono.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class triangulo : public poligono{

    private:

        string clase;

        const int lados = 3;

        int x1;
        int y1;
        int x2;
        int y2;
        int x3;
        int y3;


    public:


        triangulo (int x1i, int x2i, int x3i, int y1i, int y2i, int y3i, string clase);

        triangulo (const &otro);

        setx1(int x1i);
        setx2(int x2i);
        setx3(int x3i);

        sety1(int y1i);
        sety2(int y2i);
        sety3(int y3i);

        getx1();
        getx2();
        getx3();
        gety1();
        gety2();
        gety3();

        getlados();
        getclase();

};

#endif
```

Comment: You have way more than one issue here.

Comment: What is "xxx" in the error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the issue you mention, you need to `#include "triangulo.h"`, otherwise the compiler has no idea what this `triangulo` class you are referring to is. Also, `#include <string.h>` should be `#include <string>`.

In passing, putting `using namespace std` is not great at the best of times, but putting it in a header file is really bad. Also, if you find yourself defining member variables called `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `y1`, `y2`, and `y3`, there's a pretty good chance you have a design issue. At a minimum, sounds like a prime candidate for a `Point` `class` or `struct`, in combination with some kind of container. More likely, if you have a `poligono` base class in the first place, you'd normally kind of expect all that point functionality to be contained within that.